# What Does "GADDelayAppMeasurementInit" Delay?

Tags: objective-c, admob, google-mobile-ads

When using Google Mobile Ads SDK and integrating [User Messaging Platform SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start), Google offers to [Delay App Measurement](https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start#delay_app_measurement_optional).

You can do this programmatically or by adding `GADDelayAppMeasurementInit` to the `info.plist` and setting the `Bool` to `YES`.

It states:

> Google Mobile Ads SDK initializes app measurement and begins sending
> user-level event data to Google immediately when the app starts. ...
> However, if your app requires user consent before these events can be
> sent, you can delay app measurement...

But what does it actually do? What metrics are delayed? Does this affect whether personalised or non-personalised ads are served after providing consent?

There doesn't appear to be any more information on this anywhere.

Thank you.